# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, but I'm not sure where it's coming from

Tags: c#, dijkstra

I apologize in advance if I'm breaking any stack overflow question rules, I tried making sure everything I was doing was allowed, but I might have missed something. This is my first time actually asking a question.

I just got done with a program that uses Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest time between one station to all the other stations. My program runs, but when I type in my starting and stopping point I get these errors:

I understand what the error is, I'm just not sure where it is happening.

An unhandled exception of type `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` occurred in `mscorlib.dll`

Additional information:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

I didn't want to bombard everyone with huge amounts of code.... So I'm putting a link to the dropbox location where I have it: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z7an3eho1lkm1h9/_0bm5taT31

Again, I'm sorry if I missed a rule and I'm breaking it. Let me know if I am and I'll try to repost the question in a way that is appropriate.

Comment: This is the moment where you should learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What does the stacktrace say? If it's a debug build, the stacktrace should contain line numbers, allowing you to pinpoint the line where the error occurs.

Comment: You just need to post a section of the code where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio you can tell the debugger to break when an exception is thrown:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx

Using this technique you should be able to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two condition in your code which is mentioned below.

```
 if(Subway.Count>0)
            shortest.Add(Subway[s2]);

 int mins=0;
             if(Subway.Count>0)
             mins = Subway[s2].cost;
```

your subway list is empty still you find it item from it show it will through the exception.